# How to keep a global object in a Delphi DLL?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, delphi-2010

I have a simple DLL written in Delphi. It provides functions which operate on some read-only data, embedded as a resource. I found loading that resource on each call to be quite slow, so I want to put it in an object that sticks around between calls.

What is the right way to do this? The following works:

```
var
  MyObject: TMyObject;

function ReportSomethingAboutMyObject(): Integer; stdcall; export;

exports ReportSomethingAboutMyObject();

begin
  MyObject = TMyObject.Create;
  LoadTheResourceIntoObject(MyObject);
end.
```

But I fear memory leaks or other unexpected behavior.

I would be interested to know how the answer would be different if the object were read-write and possible non-threadsafe.

### Update 1

As requested, I will provide a more specific use case. I have a text file (ini) embedded in the DLL as a resource and I need to do lookups only. It all works way faster if I load the resource just once and keep it around as `TMemIniFile` or `TStringList` for a simpler example. After loading, the content is not going to change. In the future I'd like to be able to change the data structure for something smarter, e.g. a `TDictionary`.

For contrast, I'd like to consider a second case, where the global object is something totally different, like a database connection that I'd like to stay around between calls (since there may be very many). How should be done differently then?

Comment: You are still creating the object and loading the resource on every call. And now you are leaking that object too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something like that and ensure that the memory doesn't leak, try moving the cache object into a unit.  Put the code to load it in `initialization` and the code to clean it up in `finalization`.  These should be automatically called when the DLL is loaded and unloaded, respectively.

Comment: An another possibility is to add a finalization routine to [DllProc chain](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_DLLProc.html)

Comment: @user539484 What are the practical differences?

Comment: This is risky in a DLL because that code runs inside DllMain which has severe restrictions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So which solution do you recommend?

Comment: I would not recommend anything with so little information. Since I've no idea what `TMyObject` is, I would not be prepared to give you advice. I would say that the suggestion to use `DllProc` is rather pointless. It's simpler to use finalization.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't think it would make that much of a difference, but I provided a sample use case. Still I would like the answer to be as general as possible, i.e. not too focussed on this use case if it needn't be.

Comment: OK, having seen the update, I would suggest that the best way to make it threadsafe is to create the `TMemIniFile` in an initialization block, and destroy it in the finalization block.

Comment: @Thijs van Dien, `DllProc` way is lower level, therefore more complex. Since you library does not need to be notified about thread creation/destruction, there no more practical differences. However, that remark about "risky" is shallow, came from misreading `DllMain` article in PDSK.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So basically you're saying that @MasonWheeler's answer is OK. Still I'd like to know what kind of `TMyObject` you thought about might cause problems.

Comment: @user539484 It's not shallow. If you think that you can do anything at all inside `DllMain`, then it is you, not I, that has problems of comprehension.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien For the DB example, threading is not an issue since the connection will have affinity to the thread that created it.

Comment: This risk is if you call anything that blocks on something that needs to claim the DLL loader lock. Since DllMain runs inside the DLL loader lock, you risk deadlock. Some links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/28/63880.aspx  http://blog.barthe.ph/2009/07/30/no-stdlib-in-dllmai/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks a bunch. You might as well stick all the useful input in an answer to gain some credit (if it still matters to you now you reached 174k) - or just be satisfied that at least I get your name right nowadays. ;)

Comment: @ThijsvanDien I'm not sure any of what I said merits an answer. But thanks anyway. And as for the names, I'm not sure which of us has the trickier name!

Comment: @David Heffernan, speaking about comprehension, I didn't write that. Quantity of posts impressed an OP, however I'm a quality person, so I'm going to ask you to **prove** that code in `DllProc` chain is more "risky" than code in `finalization` section. PoC should work outside of your computer too.

Comment: @user539484 My original comment was aimed at Mason's answer. If it had been aimed at you it would have had the *at* name. Code in DllProc and finalization both run in DllMain and so there's clearly no difference, other than the ease of programming.